# Separation of hits returned from elastic by nested field value

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I've index with products there. I'm trying to separate hits returned from elastic by nested field value. There's my shortened index:

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {        
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "model_name": {
          "type": "text",          
        },
        "variants": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "attributes": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "id": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "product_attribute_id": {
                  "type": "integer"
                },               
                "value": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "id": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "product_id": {
              "type": "integer"
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And product example (there's is more variants and attributes in product - I just cut them off):

```
{
   "_index":"product_index",
   "_type":"product",
   "id":192,
   "model_name":"Some tshirt",
   "variants":[
      {
         "id":1271,
         "product_id":192,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "id":29,
               "name":"clothesSize",
               "value":"XL",
               "product_attribute_id":36740
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":1272,
         "product_id":192,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "id":29,
               "name":"clothesSize",
               "value":"L",
               "product_attribute_id":36741
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The field in question is attribute id. Let's say I want to separate products by size attribute - id 29. It would be perfect if the response would look like:

```
"hits" : [
{
   "_index":"product_index",
   "_type":"product",
   "id":192,
   "model_name":"Some tshirt",
   "variants":[
      {
         "id":1271,
         "product_id":192,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "id":29,
               "name":"clothesSize",
               "value":"XL",
               "product_attribute_id":36740
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
},     
{
   "_index":"product_index",
   "_type":"product",
   "id":192,
   "model_name":"Some tshirt",
   "variants":[      
      {
         "id":1272,
         "product_id":192,
         "attributes":[
            {
               "id":29,
               "name":"clothesSize",
               "value":"L",
               "product_attribute_id":36741
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}]
```

I thought about separate all variants in elastic request and then group them on application side by those attribute but i think it's not most elegant and above all, efficient way.
What are the elastic keywords that I should be interested in?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can get the nested `inner_hits` (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html) then use `filter_path` to reduce the response only to those fields you're interested in (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering). Bear in mind that in doing this, you may reduce the JSON to a structure that NEST's serializer cannot deserialize, so may need to use the low level client to return a string and parse yourself into a `JObject` or similar general JSON structure